# Tomcat Session Replication with Memcached,ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactory

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat Session Replication with Memcached。
Using kryo-serialize.
When startup tomcat,the error occurred。

Apache Tomcat/7.0.69 on centos6.5.
java version "1.7.0_101".

tomcat error:

```
SEVERE: The session manager failed to start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5593)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Causeotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactorlassNotFoundExceptioncom.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactorlassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactory
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.kryo.KryoTranscoderFactory.getTranscoder(KryoTranscoderFactory.java:64)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.kryo.KryoTranscoderFactory.createTranscoder(KryoTranscoderFactory.java:47)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService.createTranscoderService(MemcachedSessionService.java:495)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService.startInternal(MemcachedSessionService.java:450)
        at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.startInternal(MemcachedBackupSessionManager.java:554)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

the lib directory of tomcat:

```
 annotations-api.jar
 asm-3.2.jar
 catalina-ant.jar
 catalina-ha.jar
 catalina.jar
 catalina-tribes.jar
 ecj-4.4.2.jar
 el-api.jar
 jasper-el.jar
 jasper.jar
 jsp-api.jar
 kryo-1.04.jar
 kryo-serializers-0.11.jar
 memcached-session-manager-1.9.3.jar
 memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.9.3.jar
 minlog-1.2.jar
 msm-kryo-serializer-1.9.3.jar
 objenesis-1.4.jar
 reflectasm-1.01.jar
 servlet-api.jar
 spymemcached-2.11.1.jar
 tomcat7-websocket.jar
 tomcat-api.jar
 tomcat-coyote.jar
 tomcat-dbcp.jar
 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
 tomcat-jdbc.jar
 tomcat-util.jar
 websocket-api.jar
```

tomcat content.xml modify:

```
<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:127.0.0.1:11211"
    sticky="false"
    lockingMode="auto"
    sessionBackupAsync="false"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    sessionBackupTimeout="1000"
    transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.kryo.KryoTranscoderFactory"
    />
```

How do I fix this error？
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your kryo jar (`kryo-1.04.jar`) does not contain the dependency that kryo-serializer is asking for, i.e. `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoFactory`.

You need to get a more recent bundle of kyro in order for it to work, [any of these](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware/kryo) should do the job.